# Do you put any of your methods into the view model?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My element on the XAML page has this:

```
Command1="{Binding HCmd }
```

My view model currently has this code:

```
private ICommand nBtnCmd;

public ICommand ABtnCmd => aBtnCmd ?? (aBtnCmd = new Command(() => BtnCmd((int)Settings.dBtn, 1)));

private void BtnCmd(int pts, int col)
{
    App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrasesFrame.phrase, pts, col);
    Change.points = true;
    phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();

 }
```

Is it normal coding practice for the method `BtnCmd` to be in the view model or in the back end code that references the view model?

Comment: Good Coding practices include giving meaningful names and not short names no one but you temporary know what they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner you will understand `MVVM` pattern sooner you will start benefit from it. [Official Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) has a very good articles and explain in details what is it about.

To your question "Is it normal coding practice for the method BtnCmd to be in the view model or in the back end code that references the view model?"

It is not just normal but a preferable way if you want to benefit from the `MVVM` pattern.